# vertical line between two rowspans

Tags: tables, multirow

I am trying to build a table in which multiple instances of `\multirow` of different sizes are touching. And I have problems creating a vertical line that matches the size of the two `\multirow`s.

Here is a small example:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|cc|}
\hline
A & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{A+B}} & \multirow{4}{*}{A+B+C+D} \\
B & & \\
\cline{1-2}
C & & \\
D & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

The result is this, where the vertical line between the two `\multirow` only extends down one row:

[image: broken table]

I have found numerous examples of a solution to this problem where one of the two cells touching is only one row high and does not require `\multirow`. Is there anything I can do here?

Comment: In the second column, next row, add `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}`.

Comment: Indeed, that is the solution! Pretty simple but not _that_ intuitive, wish multicolumn would know it was spanning multiple rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

I posted an explanation somehow longer than necessary for your simple case to illustrate a  powerful tool, very helpful to proceed in more complex (real world) cases.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{multirow}   
\usepackage{bigstrut}   

\begin{document}

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|rc|}
        \hline
        A     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{A+B}} & \multirow{4}[8]{*}{A+B+C+B} \bigstrut\\
        \cline{1-1}    B     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &  \bigstrut\\
        \cline{1-2}    C     &       &  \bigstrut\\
        \cline{1-1}    D     &       &  \bigstrut\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}%
    \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%


\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The code was generated with the excellent Excel2LaTeX add-in
https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/excel2latex

I made the table in Excel and exported it to LaTeX with a copy to the clipboard and pasted it into a bare LaTeX document with some packages added.

To repeat, make sure you have unchecked the option to  the bookmarks package.

As an exercise try to eliminate the row lines between "A" and "B" and between "C" and "D", as happens in your example, without editing the LaTeX code directly.

See my answer in
[Keeping indentation and left alignment consistent](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/564409/keeping-indentation-and-left-alignment-consistent)

dealing with  a  more complicated case using the same tool, the same way.

[image: 2latex]
[image]

Comment: The problem was already solved by @Bernard comment, isn't it?

Comment: @Zarko The point of my answer was to show a very general method for dealing with complex tables, not to solve the simple particular case. I think I might be useful other users.
I  just posted a similar answer in a much more interest case to further illustrate the point.
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/564409/keeping-indentation-and-left-alignment-consistent

Comment: You not convince me to use Excel as (essential) step in design of tables in LaTeX document. Well, this is matter of taste ... (if someone already use Excel, why than (s)he not continue with Word?). For example, why someone use `tikz` or `pgfplots` if there exist professional programs with simpler user interface (at least less demanding learning curve) ... As I already say, matter of taste.

Comment: The key is the use of `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}` in the next row, as mentioned by @Bernard in the comments above. I am not an Excel user myself but this looks like a useful tool.

Comment: It is not a matter of taste, but of using the tool that best suits the task. One time, he had a list of 525 alumni, sorted by last name, in LaTeX ready to go to press and the principal decided instead to sort them by year of graduation.
Having the original list in Excel allowed the job to be done in minutes. Do you know a way to do it in LaTeX or in a simple text editor?

Comment: Mainly I work, every day, with numerical tables, with many columns calculated, reordered, etc. LaTeX is the final step, before publishing. Once a year if I am lucky.

Answer (score 0):

In `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have a command `\Block` to merge cells both horizontally and vertically and you have a key `draw` to draw the frame around the block.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|c|cc|}
\Hline
A & \Block[draw]{2-1}{A+B} & \Block{4-1}{A+B+C+D} \\
B & & \\
C & & \\
D & & \\
\Hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]